# Assign terraform output to environment variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

How can I assign terraform output to environment variable?

Let's say I have following output defined in my *main.tf*

```
output "gce_public_ip" {
    value = element(concat(google_compute_instance.vm_instance.*.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip, list("")), 0)
}
```

I would like to export `gce_public_ip`, so it will be available as environment variable `GCE_PUBLIC_IP`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [the `terraform output` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/output.html).

Not tested with your value, but it should be something like:

```
export GCE_PUBLIC_IP=$(terraform output -raw gce_public_ip)
```

Comment: You probably want to include the `-raw` arg on the output command i.e. `export GCE_PUBLIC_IP=$(terraform output -raw gce_public_ip)`